# How to remove special characters from a text file with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have a text file and have to remove all weird characters from it. I've already tried the following:

```
 (get-content C:\Users\JuanMa\Desktop\UNB\test.txt) -replace ('.','') | out-file C:\Users\JuanMa\Desktop\UNB\test2.txt
```

But this leads to an empty output - the file `test2.txt` remains empty.

This is my text file:

```
.!..p.ÿÿ.!..!   .!.           PESCATORE
.!.           LEMON SPICE S.R.L.
      600 SUR DE MULTIPLAZA ESCAZU
              3-102-599284
     TEL: 2289-8010 FAX: 2289-5129
          INFO@PESCATORECR.COM
.!..!             Terminal POS: BARRA
.!.
.!           ------------FACTURA-----------
.!      .!0    Mesa: B07
.!..!   NUMERO : 0068371  
.!.Mesa # : B07         Fecha: 25/09/2018
Mesero : CARLOS
Cajero : JOHN        Hora : 22:35:06
# Pers : 1           Comandas: 1
Apertura: 22:34      Tiempo/E: 1 Min
.!      .!..!   .!       CANT  DESCRIPCION               MONTOS
.!.---------------------------------------
   1.00 LIMONADA HIERBABUE    2,033.00
.!                SubTotal :          2,033.00
          %IVA     :            264.00
          %SER     :            203.00
.!      .!.        TOTALES :      2,501.00
.!..!             (COLONES) 
En Dolares : 4.55
.!.>> Pago: EFECTIVO> 2,555.00
>> Recibe: 2,555.00
>> Cambio: 54.00
.!      
   www.gruposinertech.com Vers.15.09A
.!.
     AUTORIZADO MEDIANTE RESOLUCION
          11-97 DE LA D.G.T.D







.i
.@
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A period (.) is ALL characters, so you asked PowerShell to replace anything with blank. What would you like to take out of the file? You will need to be more specific.

Comment: all the characters that are not a text like .!..! or .!..p.ÿÿ.!..!   .!. you can see them in the begging of the lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-replace` operator uses regular expressions, which use period to denote ANY character, so this strips out anything. If you want to remove literal periods, then prefix the period with a backslash:

```
(get-content C:\Users\JuanMa\Desktop\UNB\test.txt) -replace ('\.','') | out-file C:\Users\JuanMa\Desktop\UNB\test2.txt
```

Unfortunately this removes ALL periods, so the periods you may want to keep, e.g. in numbers are lost.

To clean out multiple bad characters, include them in square brackets. This removes 'ÿ','!'

```
(get-content C:\Users\JuanMa\Desktop\UNB\test.txt) -replace ('[ÿ!]','') | out-file C:\Users\JuanMa\Desktop\UNB\test2.txt
```

You can chain up these `-replace` operators to do multiple substitutions:

```
# Characters ÿ or !
# Replace .! at the start of the line with blank

(get-content C:\Users\JuanMa\Desktop\UNB\test.txt) `
-replace ('[ÿ!]','') `
-replace ('^.!','') |  
out-file C:\Users\JuanMa\Desktop\UNB\test2.txt
```

Comment: thanks ! Thats seems to work, I have to figure out how not to delete the periods around numbers

Comment: I recommend https://regex101.com/ as a resource if you wanted to write a Regular Expression to cope with this

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(get-content -Raw C:\Users\JuanMa\Desktop\UNB\test.txt).Replace ('.','') | out-file C:\Users\JuanMa\Desktop\UNB\test2.txt
```

Get-content return an array by default but if you specify -Raw it will return a string

Comment: yeah ! That did it, but only for the '.' I need to clean the rest of the garbage

Answer (score 1):

howdy Juan Manuel Sanchez,

the following will trim the unwanted chars from the beginning of each line in the array of lines you get from Get-Content. it acts on each line in the array without needing to iterate thru the array explicitly.

it's VERY fragile since it hard codes the items. also, it removes all the left hand padding spaces.

```
$GC_Array -creplace '^[.! pÿ]{1,}' -replace '^0 {2,}'
```

- `-creplace`  is the case-sensitive version of replace
- `^` means start at the beginning of the line
- `[]` is the character set to replace
  char list = dot, exclamation point, space, lowercase p, accented y
- `{1,}` means one or more
- the 2nd replace targets start-of-line, a zero digit, & two or more spaces

hope that helps,
lee

Comment: Im doing 

get-content C:\Users\JuanMa\Desktop\UNB\test.txt | -replace '^[.! pÿ]{1,}' | -replace '^0 {2,}'| set-content  C:\Users\JuanMa\Desktop\UNB\test2.txt

But I get -creplace : The term '-creplace' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: OK I made it to work. Its a way to clean All the white spaces or spaces that are left in the end of the file. It makes a huge one page document.

Comment: @JuanManuelSanchez - the `-replace` will not work directly after a pipe. it is an operator, not a cmdlet. [*grin*] you would need to enclose it in a `ForEach-Object` call to make that work.

however, if you use the technique i showed earlier - acting directly on an array of lines - the code will work. you can do that by removing pipes, and enclosing your `Get-Content` in `@()` so that you are operating on the whole collection of lines.

Comment: After testing in different machines I noticed that the input txt can vary depending on the computer (Im guessing its a enconding thing).

So, I have to make a more general aproach and see if there is a way to delete all kind of special characters. Since I cant know for sure how its the txt going to be like.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @JuanManuelSanchez - probably not. you need to have SOME way to determine what _IS_ & what _IS NOT_ valid. you can likely target all accented characters, but your 1st example has a lowercase "p" in the garbage characters AND it had a zero in the unwanted characters. that makes targeting very, very error prone. as i mentioned, the solution i posted is _fragile_. [*grin*]